# How to get the filtered rows in ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Using `ui-grid` I want to get a list of all the filtered data rows using the filter.

In the plunker below I have the original data of 500 items filtered down to 61.
Now how do I get a list of those 61 entities?

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/532hzRVZLqEuzXvsmDnN?p=preview)

If I use the following code I only get the rows rendered on the screen

```
var _renderedRows = $scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.renderedRows;
```

Clicking the button at the bottom of that plunker shows the number of filtered rows which is only 14 as opposed to 61.
That works perfectly if there are 14 or less in my filter as I can access the entity object from the above.
But I can't see any property in the grid that exposes the filtered rows.

So how can I get the list of 61 so I can pass them into another function to perform actions on them?

Comment: This is an answer to a similar question. It acknowledges not only visible rows, but **rows that are actually filtered**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36047012/4732117

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [PublicApi](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi) to get the current visible rows count

```
$scope.filteredRows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
```

Here is the updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EkNUtrteHizyx1iwuJpA) (Hint: You have to click the "Get filtered rows" button)

Comment: I believe this only gets those set to visible, which if you have paging enabled will max out at the page size. Haven't come across something that specifically gets *all* filtered rows (across all pages) yet myself, but I'm looking...

Comment: if you use grouping and treeNodes, the property `treeNode.row.visible === true`, worked for me, to get filtered grouped rows. Without pagination.