# How to Get Filtered data from paged ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'd like to get filtered data from a ui-grid when the paging feature is enabled. In general case I used

```
 $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {

                if ($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[1].filter.term != "" && $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[1].filter.term != undefined) {
                    var dd =$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
                    console.log(dd);
            });
```

but the code doesn't work well when the paging is enabled, it return only rows of the first page. but I need all the filtered data.

the easiest solution is filter data source based on the filter term but it decreases the performance dramatically.

any advice?

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** I didn't try it with pagination, just grouping, but hope it gives you a hint.

Try using the `rowsVisibleChanged` event together with the `filterChanged` event. You have to use both because if you use the `filterChanged` event alone it won't work since it's launched before the rows are actually filtered. I use a flag variable (`filterChanged`) to know if a filter was modified.

Then, use something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) to filter the `$scope.gridApi.grid.rows` that have the `visible` property set to `true`:

```
// UI-Grid v.3.0.7
var filterChanged = false;

$scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function() {
    filterChanged = true;
});

$scope.gridApi.core.on.rowsVisibleChanged($scope, function() {
    if(!filterChanged){
        return;
    }
    filterChanged = false;
    // The following line extracts the filtered rows
    var filtered = _.filter($scope.gridApi.grid.rows, function(o) { return o.visible; });
    var entities = _.map(filtered, 'entity'); // Entities extracted from the GridRow array
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: I am trying the same thing, but for some reason `filterChanged` is not triggered when filtering the table. Any idea why could that be?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to export filtered data across all pagination via [uiGridExporterService](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.service:uiGridExporterService) service. Thanks to @Patricio's above answer for the hint.

```
//you can set it to ALL or VISIBLE or SELECTED
var columnsDownloadType = uiGridExporterConstants.ALL;

//get all the visible rows across all paginations
var filtered = _.filter(grid.api.grid.rows, function (o) {
    return o.visible;
});

//get the entities of each of the filtered rows
var entities = _.map(filtered, 'entity');

//get all or visible column headers of this grid depending on the columnsDownloadType
var exportColumnHeaders = grid.options.showHeader ? uiGridExporterService.getColumnHeaders(grid, columnsDownloadType) : [];

var exportData = [];
/**this lodash for-each loop will covert the grid data into below array of array format 
* [[{value:'row1col1value'},{value:'row1col2value'}],[{value:'row2col1value'},{value:'row2col2value'}].....]
* uiGridExporterService.formatAsCsv expects it in this format
**/
_.each(entities, function (row) {
    var values = [];
    _.each(exportColumnHeaders, function (column) {
        var value = row[column.name];
        values.push({value: value});
    });
    exportData.push(values);
});

//format the header,content in csv format
var csvContent = uiGridExporterService.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, exportData, ',');

//export as csv file
uiGridExporterService.downloadFile(grid.options.exporterCsvFilename, csvContent, grid.options.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the custom exporter and it worked!

- Prerequisites :

  ```
  enableSelectAll:true,
  multiSelect:true,
  ```
- your controller needs :

  ```
  uiGridExporterService,uiGridExporterConstants
  ```
- app module needs :

  ```
  "ui.grid.selection"   ,"ui.grid.exporter"

  $scope.exportCSV = function(){
                       var exportService=uiGridExporterService;
                       var grid=$scope.gridApi.grid;
                       var fileName="myfile.csv";

                       exportService.loadAllDataIfNeeded(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE).then(function() {
                         var exportColumnHeaders = exportService.getColumnHeaders(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);

                         $scope.gridApi.selection.selectAllVisibleRows();

                         var exportData = exportService.getData(grid, uiGridExporterConstants.SELECTED,uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
                         var csvContent = exportService.formatAsCsv(exportColumnHeaders, exportData, grid.options.exporterCsvColumnSeparator);
                         exportService.downloadFile(fileName, csvContent, grid.options.exporterOlderExcelCompatibility);
                         $scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows();
                       });
                     }
  ```